# Is my local variable redundant when assigning value from array filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am getting a warning in WebStorm that Local variable lessThanOne is redundant.  I need to return it as the value of a function.

```
const nums = [8, 1, 1.3, 0.9, 0.4, -1];

  const lessThanOne = nums.filter(number =>{
    return number < 1});
  return lessThanOne;
```

I have tried refactoring but nothing I have tried (removing the local variable) seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried **return nums.filter(number =>{ return number < 1});** ?

Comment: You probably do not need `return` inside your `filter` condition.

Comment: You should do ```return nums.filter(number => number < 1);``` instead, no need to add a return inside the filter.

Comment: The warning is just saying that you should not use extra variables if you do not need them. It is really just a style preference.

Comment: good point @JoanLara that is even better

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the code inside a function as follows:

```
const nums = [8, 1, 1.3, 0.9, 0.4, -1];

function lessThanOne() {
  const lessThanOne = nums.filter((number) => {
    return number < 1;
  });
  return lessThanOne;
}

lessThanOne();
```

You can also pass the nums array as a parameter to the function.

Comment: The point is less redundant unneeded code. This is actually creating more unneeded code and has a variable name that duplicates the function name. Although it technically doesn't affect it, using a variable name that is the same as the function name is bad programming behavoirs.